# Cannot upload files from React to .net Core 5 with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, axios, .net-5

I am trying to upload file with a multiple objects e.g. I have a student who wants to upload multiple scanned/downloaded files. Everything must drag and drop, so when user drag and drops files I generate objects in react application and post via axois with **_header["Content-Type"] =  "multipart/form-data"**.

But I am not able to see the file in sent object. What am I missing?

```
public class CourseFile{
    public Guid StudentId{get;set;}
    public string FileName{get;set;}
    public boolean IsPdf{get;set;}
    public IFormFile File{get;set;}
}
```

**StudentController**

```
[Route("upload-files")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm] IList<CourseFile> models)
{
    var _req = Request;
    var files = Request.Form.Files; // I can see files here
    var file = files.First();
    var modelProperty = file.Name; // I can see model property here
    foreach (var courseFile in models)
    {
         UploadFiles(courseFile.File) // Always null
    }
}
```

React Code Only making of object

```
private getFormData(data: any, form: FormData, idx = -1, baseKey = "") {
if (Array.isArray(data))
  data.forEach((item, idx) => this.getFormData(item, form, idx));
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    if (!key) return;
    let _key =
      idx > -1
        ? baseKey
          ? key.indexOf("files") >= 0
            ? `${baseKey}[][${key}]`
            : `${baseKey}[${idx}][${key}][]`
          : `${key}[${idx}]`
        : key;
      let itemData = data[key];
      if (Array.isArray(itemData)) {
        itemData.forEach((item, idx) => this.getFormData(item, form, idx, key));
        return form;
      }
      if (key.indexOf("files") >= 0) {
        form.append(`${baseKey}[${idx}][File][]`, itemData);
      } else if (itemData) {
        form.append(_key, itemData);
      } else {
        form.append(_key, "");
      }
    });
return form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be here:

```
form.append(`${baseKey}[${idx}][File][]`, itemData);
```

The key/name seems to be quite finicky with files. I ended up having to change this to the following in order to work:

```
form.append(`${baseKey}[${idx}].File`, itemData);
```

I made a simplified version of your code (see below) to do my testing. I tried multiple combinations, such as you had `[File][]`, and `[File]`, and finally `.File`. The last was the only one that resulted in the file being correctly set.

*Edit: This only seems to apply to the `IFormFile` key. I was able to do either `[StudentId]` or `.StudentId`, and either of those would work.

fetch code:

```
  const baseKey = 'models';
  const data = new FormData();
  for (let idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++) {
    const b = new Blob(['This is my blob content ' + idx], { type: 'text/plain' });
    data.append(`${baseKey}[${idx}].StudentId`, idx);
    data.append(`${baseKey}[${idx}].File`, b);
  }
  fetch('/home/uploadfiles', { method: 'post', body: data });
```

controller method:

```
public class CourseFile
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm] IList<CourseFile> models)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: It did work as expected. Thanks @David784